# resizing and vectorise an image

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have been asked by a journal to resize and vectorize a flow chart kind of image, originally drawn in ppt format and then converted to tiff.
could you please provide me a link or service that may be able to solve my problem with image enhancement.
I did try out vectorizer, adobe illustrator, and imresizer kind links but they all failed. and the image fails on quality, resolution and indistinctness quotient.
the provided specifications are 
Width = 8.5 inches OR Width= 7791px

Height = 11 inches OR Height = 4724px

Pixels/Centimeter = 300 (DPI) (minimum)

All figure should be in vector scale
Please provide me a solution.

Comment: How exactly did Illustrator fail? Are you attempting to Auto Trace it? Are you not able to draw/recreate the image yourself, from scratch? If the document was originally a PPT file, can't you get access to the original file? Sharing an image of the chart will also help. Please add details to your question if you want solutions.

Comment: In *most* instances for things like flow charts, it is **much** easier to *redraw* them with Illustrator than attempting to trace anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately graphs and tables do not easily trace back into vector format because the fine lines and small characters are too blurred.

To vectorize a graph that's bitmapped it is best to draw it new in a vector format.

You can do this manually in illustrator, recreating all elements of the graph in the new size.

Because it was "drawn" originally in PowerPoint there is a good chance that you can recreate it in PowerPoint using the chart tools.

Its unlikely that someone drew a table and chart in PowerPoint using the shape tools. Much more likely that they used the graph generating tools.

You just need to go into PowerPoint and recreate the graph. Once you select the chart type you just enter the values into a table and it draws it for you. Try to match styles and colors if needed. They may have used the default chart style.

You can choose size and proportion here. Make the new graph meet the client specifications.

Now to export the graph from PowerPoint, save the slide as a .PDF or Print to .PDF, or save as an .EMF and open in Illustrator.

Alternately, open the Notes Page in PowerPoint (used to print handouts and speaker notes) and then select the slide with the select tool. Copy the selection and then paste it into Illustrator.

There are other methods for transferring the graphic from .ppt to .ai, check them out.

Answer (score 0):

There are commercial services which vectorize images. They can redraw it, if needed. Some of them even advertise "100% manual conversion". It's business and costs money, but that money can be well used, if you are in a hurry. Search for "vectorize image service".

There exists image vectorizing software which is intended for CAD and other "no art" images. They can interpret also your image, guess perfectly straight lines and simple arcs, but still there's a lot of manual fine tuning to do before the result is fully usable - all that assuming you have a sharp high resolution TIFF image, not a blurry photo.

Consider to redraw it by yourself. It can be laborous, but if it's a flowchart with no arty pieces, it should be technically possible.

PS

To get some more comprehensive answers you should include a portion of the image to show the severity level of the problem.